# Spring Security + Remember me support + auto redirect

Tags: java, cookies, spring-security

I got a spring + hibernate project that uses spring security for authentication and everything works like a charm. i have the spring-security.xml below :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">  

<!-- enable use-expressions -->  
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"> 
 <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="isAuthenticated()" />
 <intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="isAuthenticated()" /> 


  <form-login 
    login-page="/" 
    authentication-failure-url="/?error"  
    username-parameter="username" 
    password-parameter="password" 
    default-target-url="/home" />  

   <!-- access denied page -->  
   <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
   <!-- logout handling -->
   <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/?logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE" />  
   <!-- enable csrf protection  <csrf />  -->  
   <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="clarkerpi" />

  </http>  

  <beans:bean id="rememberMeServices"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:property name="tokenRepository" ref="customTokenRepository" />
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <beans:property name="key" value="clarkerpi" />
 </beans:bean> 

 <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />  
 </authentication-manager>   

 <beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
 </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

Almost everything works. I can login and check "remember me" and it creates cookies, persists tokens and all that. If i erase JSESSIONID cookie i can still access protected resources.

But i have a question...

if i access localhost/projectname/ , and "/" being my login page, is there any native way ( spring security ) of redirecting to target-url, which is /home for those with the remember_me cookie? I can access any protected resource with no problem, but i'd like to type localhost/projectname/ and access /home. Of course, let the login page to be available for non-remember-me logins.

Question 2 ) I'm very new to spring security + cookie handling, is ok to delete JSESSIONID and Remember_me cookies like i'm doing in logout ? Or?

thanks in advance,
//fferrandini

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

The spring security does it job perfectly. When you have "remember_me" active and access protected resources it does work like a charm and that is all his job. Spring security doenst take care of redirects or "what i want to do with this after auth"...

the solution was quite simple.

I found this method at mkyong  :

```
private boolean isRememberMeAuthenticated() {

    Authentication authentication =          SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication == null) {
       return false;
    }

    return RememberMeAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication.getClass());
 }
```

Which you can set it in a controller or even better a filter. I set it in my login mapping... "/". If true redirect to /home otherwise let login happen.

hope this help somebody!

spring you 're beautiful !! lol

Answer (score 0):

Change your login page like this "/login" and 
`<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()"/>` and map "/" to "/home"